# Collapsible text boxes aren't displaying properly

Tags: html, css

I made a working concept in CodePen of what I want to add into my site. But when I put the code into my website it doesn't function correctly. I can't find what's getting lost in translation here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**How I want it to work**
http://codepen.io/Mdade89/pen/JKkYGq

**How it's currently working**
https://premierdisability.com/faq-new/

```css
.question {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: auto !important;
  font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 280px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.answer {
  display:none;
  font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.show {
  display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.hide:target + .show {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hide:target {
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hide:target ~ .answer {
  display:inline;
  text-decoration: none;

}

@media print {
  .hide, .show {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>This is a title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>



  <div class="question">
  <a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1">First question</a>
  <a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1">First question after click</a>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Here is the answer</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
  <a href="#hide2" class="hide" id="hide2">Second question</a>
  <a href="#show2" class="show" id="show2">Second question after click</a>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Here is the answer</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
  <a href="#hide3" class="hide" id="hide3">Third question</a>
  <a href="#show3" class="show" id="show3">Third question after click</a>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Here is the answer</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
  <a href="#hide4" class="hide" id="hide4">Fourth question</a>
  <a href="#show4" class="show" id="show4">Fourth question after click</a>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Here is the answer</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `<br>` tags after first anchor:

```
<a href="#hide3" class="hide" id="hide3">Third question</a>
<br>
<a href="#show3" class="show" id="show3">Third question after click</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a href="#hide3" class="hide" id="hide3">Third question</a>
<a href="#show3" class="show" id="show3">Third question after click</a>
```

It happens because the selector `.hide:target + .show` gets the exactly next element of html.

Comment: Interesting I wasn't actually adding in any <br>'s but WP was adding them in unless they were on the same line.

Comment: Yes, it's something from framework, you could try using the '~' selector intead '+' to get .show

Answer (score 0):

This is working in CodePen because it's not appending the target href ("#hide3" for example), to the URL because the CodePen is inside of an iframe and doesn't affect it's parent page. Your site is appending the href of the element you click to the URL, and then the following CSS is hiding that element:

```
.hide:target {
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```